# Merge file and diffs into a new file in Python

Tags: python, file, merge, compare, difflib

I'm trying to merge a file and some changes made to it.
For example, if i had the file:

```
This is Line 1
This is Line 2
This is Line 3
```

and I have changed it to:

```
This is Line 1
This is Line 3
This one is another line
```

I would be getting this output from `difflib.unified_diff`:

```
--- test.txt
+++ test2.txt
@@ -29,1 +29,1 @@
-2+3@@ -36,0 +36,4 @@
+o+n+e+ @@ -39,1 +43,9 @@
-L+a+n+o+t+h+e+r+ +l@@ -43,2 +55,0 @@
- -3
```

I want to be able to get only this output, and the original file, and merge them into getting the second file.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: FWIW, difflib assumes it's input will be an iterable of "lines". When given a raw string it does the diff at the char level rather than the line level. That results in a lot more `+` and `-` than would normally be expected.

Answer (score 2):

At the end I found a library called "diff_match_patch" which has exactly what I've been searching for.
Look here for more information:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Comment: meanwhile moved to https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch